# div is not properly aligned

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with class = "row". In that div, I am trying to align two divs in same row. But somehow, its not working. [image]

Here's the html code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" style="width: 50%;" class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="offlineRouterCnt!=0">
      <strong>Number of offline Routers : {{offlineRouterCnt}} </strong>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style = "width : 27%">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ALL</button>
      </div>
    <input ng-model="naviagtion.searchText" class="form-control" focus-dir placeholder="Search Routers here"></input> 
      <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="clearSearchAndFilters();">
        <span class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can someone help me how to do align them in same row?

Comment: Both of your `<div>` elements have an inline `width` style. This will override Bootstrap's style. Why are you manually specifying this?

Comment: even without specifying the width, it doesn't work

Comment: Same code is working in my PC. They are in one row..

Comment: Your code works as per your expectation and just have a look out this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/qu9qye4f/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you specifying col-md-4, col-sm-4 and col-xs-4. Bootstrap scales, so you should only need to enter col-xs-4 & col-xs-8.

I think the browser is getting confused on which one is being declared and stacking them, rather than scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with Firefox 10.3 (macOS High Sierra). But I guess that some browsers could have conflicts with your custom inline `width` style. Try to remove it..the width of floated elements was set from the bootstrap classes.

So the final code could be:

```
    <div class = "row">
     <div class = "col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="offlineRouterCnt!=0">
      <strong>Number of offline Routers : {{offlineRouterCnt}} </strong>
     </div>

     <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ALL</button>
      </div>
      <input ng-model="naviagtion.searchText" class="form-control" focus-dir placeholder="Search Routers here"></input> 
      <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="clearSearchAndFilters();">
       <span class="fa fa-times fa-1x"></span>
      </span>
     </div>
   </div>
```